# Asus Router: Allow traffic between wired and wireless devices on internal network

Tags: wireless-networking, switching

I have an ASUS RT-AC87U router (on firmware version 3.0.0.4.382_51641-g46d2311).

I am trying to connect from a Wi-Fi connected Windows laptop to an Ubuntu VM running on a wired Windows desktop PC within the internal network but am failing miserably. Specifically, I am trying ping and MySQL connections. In the case of pings, I just get 'Destination host unreachable' responses, and the MySQL connections timeout.

I can happily communicate between the Ubuntu instance and the desktop PC, but can reach neither from the Windows laptop.

So far, I have been unsuccessful in locating any option in the router configuration that might allow me to enable this traffic. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, make sure you have Client Isolation turned off in the Advanced wireless settings of the router. This setting makes it so the wifi clients cannot communicate on the LAN. Secondly, troubleshoot that desktop windows client and make sure that the windows firewall is allowing incoming connections from the LAN. Once you can access the windows desktop, then start working on Ubuntu. Ensuring that Ubuntu firewall or configuration settings is not blocking incoming requests. In your VM network adapter settings, use bridge mode so your VM gets an IP from the LAN, instead of a NAT address.

Comment: Also make sure your wireless router is on the same subnet as the main router and turn DHCP OFF on the wireless router. Make sure you hooked up a LAN port (not WAN port) on the wireless router to your network.